# If Session match string

Tags: c#

I got a little problem. I got a if statement which says if Session isn't equal 3, then do something, and if that isn't true, then do something else. My problem is just, that it isn't working proberly.

I've already tried:
1)

```
if (Session["userrank"] != "3")
{
   pnlAdmin.Visible = false;
}
else
{
   pnlAdmin.Visible = true;
}
```

2)

```
if (Session["userrank"].ToString() != "3")
{
   pnlAdmin.Visible = false;
}
else
{
   pnlAdmin.Visible = true;
}
```

3)

```
if ((string)Session["userrank"] != "3")
{
   pnlAdmin.Visible = false;
}
else
{
   pnlAdmin.Visible = true;
}
```

4)

```
if (((string)Session["userrank"]) != "3")
{
   pnlAdmin.Visible = false;
}
else
{
   pnlAdmin.Visible = true;
}
```

but none of them seems to work. And i have already checked if there's a Session called userrank that is getting the result 3.

sorry for the "stupid" question. I'm kind of new to C# & ASP.net.

Best Regards,
Anton

Comment: There's no error, but the pnladmin is visible no matter what the userrank is.

Comment: Have you tried just `Session["userrank"] != 3` ?

Comment: All of the above should work, and it seems that your problem lies elsewhere.  Try to 1) set `pnlAdmin.Visible = false` without any `if` statements at all, and see if it disappears. If that works, then try to explicitly set `Session["userrank"] = "3"` before the `if` statements, and see if they fire.

Comment: @Ruslan actually the `ToString()` example would work even if it was `int`.

Comment: Are you getting any exception with any of the code snippet above ?  Also inspect the `Session["userrank"]` in a watch window and see what is the exact value and its data type.

Comment: @dman2306 You're right. Edited to remove that statement

Comment: Where is that code, e.g. is it in a button click, page_load or some other function? Secondly, what is the default setting of the visibility for `pnlAdmin`? These could be useful to note.

Comment: You've got the boolean assignments the wrong way round. Debugging would've shown this...

Comment: -eouw0o83hf Yes :-)
-Ruslan I'll check if i got the rest of my code, right :-). I've tried to put visible to false without any if, they disappears.
-Habib Checked, and it's 3
-JB King It's in a Page load. 
-Joe I'll try to debug :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your code sets `pnlAdmin.Visible = false;` if whatever is in `Session["userrank"]` is *not* 3.

It sets `pnlAdmin.Visible = true;` if whatever is in `Session["userrank"]` is 3.

You said it is 3; therefore, the panel should be visible. And that seems to be what is happening.